# Jquery Insert a table row after the selected table row

Tags: jquery

I am trying to insert a table row after the row the user has selected:

Here is the fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/tonymaloney1971/ykxgy6dj/2/

So, if the user selects Product 0, we insert a new  after Product 0.

At the moment I am trying insertAfter but it is deleting the next table row?

$('#tableBody tr').on('click','button', function() {
            var insertData = "

- Q
- W
- E
- R
- Y

";
            var insertAfter = $(this).closest('tr');

```
        if($(this).text()  =='+')
        {
            $(this).text('-');
            //I would like to insert a new table row underneath the current selected table row?
            insertAfter.insertAfer(insertData);
        }
        else
        {
            $(this).text('+');
        }
    });
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to practice on `dom traversing`

```
$(document).ready( function () {            
    $('#List li').hide();

    $('#tableBody tr').on('click','button', function() {
        var insertData = "<tr><td><ul><li>Q</li><li>W</li><li>E</li><li>R</li><li>Y</li></ul></td></tr>";
        var insertAfter = $(this).parent();

        if($(this).text()  =='+')
        {
            $(this).text('-');
            //I would like to insert a new table row underneath the current selected table row?
            insertAfter.append(insertData);
        }
        else
        {
            $(this).text('+');
        }
    });                              
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Ahmet Can Güven's answer is very close. I had to make some minor changes for it to work. The [documentation for insertAfter](https://api.jquery.com/insertAfter/) helps us understand why.

```
$(document).ready( function () {            
$('#List li').hide();

$('#tableBody tr').on('click','button', function() {
    var $insertData = $("<tr><td><ul><li>Q</li><li>W</li><li>E</li><li>R</li><li>Y</li></ul></td></tr>");
    var $insertAfter = $(this).parent();

    if($(this).text()  =='+')
    {
        $(this).text('-');
        //I would like to insert a new table row underneath the current selected table row?
        $insertData.insertAfter($insertAfter);
    }
    else
    {
        $(this).text('+');
    }
});
```

});